# Importing custom modules doesn't work (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting straight to the point:

```
import Activities
# File directory should be Activities,Play,Football then the function mcball.
# For example: This doesn't work
Activities.play.football.mcball()
# Activities, play, and football are files. mcball is the function.
# No other assortment works, I tried.
# Even "from ... Import ... as ..." doesn't work
#help
```

Doesn't work, no idea why.

Also, everything is custom. "Activities" is not a module i got from the internet.

Answer (score 2):

If you only `import` the top-level `Activities` package, the inner modules will not automatically be loaded, unless the `Activities/__init__.py` file imports them for you. By default, it won't do anything, so you need to import the actual module, with:

```
import Activities.play.football
```

Now you should be able to call `Activities.play.football.mcball()` successfully.